# Python: created a list of names that I need to run as functions. error: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, function, variables

I'm trying to convert a list into callable functions. I'm writing a top level program to interface with a program that reads different data types.

I previously loaded a module that has these functions defined as well as many others, but we only want to use these 4. We want to be able to adjust from a top level the dataList

```
    dataList= ['sat1', 'sat2', 'sat3', 'sat4'] #(top line input by user)
    readData = ['ob.rd_'+L for L in dataList] 
    for n in range(0,np.size(dataList)): readData[n]('file.'+dataList[n])
```

Loaded module has functions ob.rd_sat1, ob.rd_sat2, ob.rd_sat3, etc (over 50 different  read functions)  defined and ready to go. I generate a list with only the functions I want to call. list of function names but defined as string not variable/function names

Here is where I am pulling my hair out by the roots. I cannot get the program to recognize the list of names as functions.

I get

```
Error: 'str' object is not callable.
```

I've googled this but cannot find any answer that works. Seems simple but ....

Comment: Those are strings, and try as you might, python is not going to interpret them as function names...

Comment: *sound of head hitting wall* repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

For the third statement use

```
for n in range(0,np.size(dataList)): globals()[readData[n]]('file.'+dataList[n])
```

In case the functions are not global, use `locals` instead of `globals`!

Update 1:

As @Bryan Oakley has pointed out,
you can also use

```
dataList= ['sat1', 'sat2', 'sat3', 'sat4']
readData = ['rd_'+L for L in dataList]
for n in range(0,np.size(dataList)): getattr(ob, readData[n])('file.'+dataList[n])
```

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'obs.rd_sat1 with either globals() or locals()

Comment: readData = [obs.rd_sat1,obs.rd_sat2,obs.rd_sat3,obs.rd_sat4] works after I load up the functions, but then there are two places the user has to add a choice (and two places where they can screw up.)

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are in a module, or are methods on an object, you can use `getattr` to convert a string to the function of the same name.

### Example:

```
import random

names = ("randint", "uniform")

for name in names:
    func = getattr(random, name)
    result = func(0,100)
    print("{}: {}".format(name, result))
```

In your case, if you want to convert `"sat1"` into the function `ob.rd_sat1`, you can do it like this:

```
import ob
...
dataList= ['sat1', 'sat2', 'sat3', 'sat4'] 
funcs = [getattr(ob, "rd_" + name) for name in dataList]
```